# AWS S3 getObject() causing HTTP Connection Time Out

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to retrieve a File (asdf.txt) that I manually uploaded to my AWS S3 Bucket. Let's call it "myBucket". I have set the permissions on the bucket and the file to be completely accessible to all. When I call `getObject()` I get the an error saying that the `Connection timed out`. Here is my stacktrace:

```
Dec 12, 2014 2:51:31 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection timed out: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:523)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:402)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3699)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Dec 12, 2014 2:51:53 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection timed out: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:523)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:402)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3699)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Dec 12, 2014 2:52:14 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection timed out: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:523)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:402)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3699)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Dec 12, 2014 2:52:36 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection timed out: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:523)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:402)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3699)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request:             Connection timed out: connect
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:471)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3699)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:523)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:402)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
... 9 more
```

here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
    s3.setEndpoint("s3.amazonaws.com");
    s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1));
    S3Object obj = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("myBucket", "asdf.txt"));
    System.out.println(obj.getBucketName());
}
```

I have also tried it a few different ways. The modified lines are shown below:

```
s3.setEndpoint("https://myBucketName.s3.amazonaws.com");

S3Object obj = s3.getObject("myBucket", "asdf.txt");
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this happen consistently still?  Why don't you try the specific endpoint for your bucket as defined here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region.  Specifically: s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sethwm, but it was a proxy issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a proxy issue. I just needed to specify the proxy configuration and instantiate the client with the configurations and it worked

```
AwsSyncClientBuilder builder =  AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();

ClientConfiguration cc = new ClientConfiguration();
cc.setProxyHost("<proxyAddress>");
cc.setProxyPort(<proxyPort>);

AWSCredentialsProvider credentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();

AmazonS3Client s3 = (AwsSyncClientBuilder) builder
        .withClientConfiguration(cc)
        .withCredentials(credentials)
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
```

Comment: how did you configure your config?

Comment: pls see the edit for the solution that worked for me

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 3):

U have to configure AmazonS3Client with following properties:

1. connectionTimeout=50000 in ms
2. maxConnections=500
3. socketTimeout=50000 in ms
4. maxErrorRetry=10

And don't use `Transfermanager` for upload and download
Use:

```
AmazonS3Client(AWSCredentials awsCredentials, ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)
```

see:[properties](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html)